# Using a non-copyable, non-movable type of member variable in a template class

Tags: c++

I have some classes that look like this:

```
struct foo
{
    foo() = delete;
    explicit foo(int id) :
        id(id)
    {}
    virtual ~foo() = default;

    int id;
};

template<typename T>
struct MyClass : foo
{
    MyClass() = delete;
    MyClass(int id, T value) :
        foo(id),
        value(value)
    {}

    T value;
}
```

And it has worked pretty well up until now where `T` is a `double`, a `bool`, etc.
Unfortunately, CPU manufacturers decided to start putting more logical cores in their products, and now I have to write a bunch of multithreaded code (thanks guys).

The problem arises when trying to do something like

```
MyClass<std::atomic_flag> bar{0, ?????????????} //ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT doesnt fix it
```

As it attempts to use the deleted copy constructor `std::atomic_flag(const std::atomic_flag&)`. I can see where its trying to do the copy, and the only possible solution I've come up with would involve manual allocation of memory and almost by-hand construction of members using placement-new.

Is there an easier way of doing this? How might the constructor of `MyClass<T>` be structured to allow generic types as well as special things that don't want to be moved/copied?

I'm using MSVC v140, so no C++17 or later features :(

Comment: "*almost by-hand construction of members using placement-new*" I don't know how that would help in this situation. At some point, you'd have to do `new(ptr) ImmobileType(...)`, so what exactly is going in `...` here? Because if it's an instance of `ImmobileType`, then that statement will fail to compile. Your example is too abstract to really be able to suggest any solution, since it's unclear what `MyClass` is, what its relationship to `T` is supposed to be, or why it has a constructor that takes a `T` if you want `T` to be able to be an immobile type.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that the only specified use of `ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT` is in initialization of the form `std::atomic_flag flag = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;`. Notably, this means passing it as a constructor argument is not guaranteed to work anyway. MSVC might provide other guarantees, but I don't know if that's the case.

Comment: @Nicol Without wanting to give too much away, the logic behind these is for flexible "attachment" of some value to the base type `foo`. One class may attach `bool` and set this depending on whether or not that particular instance has been touched, or a `double` may be attached to represent some sort of value derived from other instances, such as local particle density. It's not a great design, but we've managed to dig ourselves into this rut and now trying to make the best of a bad situation. In my particular case, attaching a `bool` results in a data race that an `atomic_flag` would avoid.

Comment: @N.Shead Absolutely so. It was the only thing that made the red lines go away, but expectedly failed at compile time.

Comment: I suspect you are actually looking for `std::atomic<bool>` instead.

Comment: @eerorika No dice, doesn't work for the same reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than taking an instance of the object to create, you can construct it inside your object by instead taking parameters of the type you wish to construct your class with. This will not work directly with `std::atomic_flag` due to the limitations of initializing with `ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT` (until C++20, that is), but would be fine with something like `std::atomic<bool>`.

For example:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct MyClass : foo {
  MyClass() = delete;

  // list of parameters to pass to value's constructor
  // if this is only going to be with primitive-like types,
  // you could take Args by value instead of forwarding reference
  template <typename... Args>
  explicit MyClass(int id, Args&&... args) 
    : foo(id), value(std::forward<Args>(args)...) 
  {}

  T value;
};
```

Then you should be able to do

```cpp
MyClass<std::atomic<bool>> bar{0, false};
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick! I'd encountered the variadic version elsewhere but didn't think to try it with `atomic<bool>`. Thanks!